# INSERT INTO doesnt work (only at one point)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a problem...
I have a form on my webpage where the admin is able to create an event via an sql "INSERT INTO" command.
On the same site he is able to view the registrations for those events and is able to accept or decline those registrations via an sql "UPDATE" command.
THe whole registrations part works just fine... but not the Event creation...
The code saves all the needed data of the form (date, time, etc...) and goves back a $check variable, if the variable is true, all data is received and the code sends the "INSERT INTO" command... which doesnt work... the $chekc variable is true...

This is the code for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="number" name="Tag" title="Tag" placeholder="Tag" Required>
<input type="number" name="Monat" title="Monat" placeholder="Monat" Required>
<input type="number" name="Jahr" title="Jahr" placeholder="Jahr" Required>
<input type="number" name="Stunde" title="Stunde" placeholder="Stunde" Required>
<input type="number" name="Minute" title="Minute" placeholder="Minute" Required>
<input type="text" name="Ort" title="Ort" placeholder="Ort" Required>
<input type="number" name="Preis" title="Preis" placeholder="Preis" Required>
<input type="number" name="AHelfer" title="AHelfer" placeholder="Aufbau Helfer" Required>
<input type="number" name="BHelfer" title="BHelfer" placeholder="Abbau Helfer" Required>
<input type="submit" name="Erstellen" title="Erstellen" value="Erstellen">
</form>
```

this is the code which verifies and insets the data:

```
if (!empty($_POST[Erstellen]))
    {
        $check = true;
        if (!empty($_POST[Tag]))
        {
            $Tag = str_replace('\'', '', str_replace('"', '', $_POST["Tag"]));
        }else{
            $check = false;
        }
        if (!empty($_POST[Monat]))
        {
            $Monat = str_replace('\'', '', str_replace('"', '', $_POST["Monat"]));
        }else{
            $check = false;
        }
        if (!empty($_POST[Jahr]))
        {
            $Jahr = str_replace('\'', '', str_replace('"', '', $_POST["Jahr"]));
        }else{
            $check = false;
        }
        if (!empty($_POST[Stunde]))
        {
            $Stunde = str_replace('\'', '', str_replace('"', '', $_POST["Stunde"]));
        }else{
            $check = false;
        }
        if (!empty($_POST[Minute]))
        {
            $Minute = str_replace('\'', '', str_replace('"', '', $_POST["Minute"]));
        }else{
            $check = false;
        }
        if (!empty($_POST[Ort]))
        {
            $Ort = str_replace('\'', '', str_replace('"', '', $_POST["Ort"]));
        }else{
            $check = false;
        }
        if (!empty($_POST[Preis]))
        {
            $Preis = str_replace('\'', '', str_replace('"', '', $_POST["Preis"]));
        }else{
            $check = false;
        }
        if (!empty($_POST[AHelfer]))
        {
            $AHelfer = str_replace('\'', '', str_replace('"', '', $_POST["AHelfer"]));
        }else{
            $check = false;
        }
        if (!empty($_POST[BHelfer]))
        {
            $BHelfer = str_replace('\'', '', str_replace('"', '', $_POST["BHelfer"]));
        }else{
            $check = false;
        }

        if ($check)
        {
            echo 'check ';
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Veranstaltungen (Tag, Monat, Jahr, Stunde, Minute, Preis, Ort, AHelfer, BHelfer) VALUES ('$Tag', '$Monat', '$Jahr', $Stunde', '$Minute', '$Preis', '$Ort', '$AHelfer', '$BHelfer')";
            $eintragen = mysqli_query($verbindung, $sql);
            echo $eintragen;
        }
```

[This is the db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz8lO.png)

Comment: post your code not image

Comment: Copy the code from your IDE and paste it here instead of attaching the screenshot

Comment: you probably need to add quotes around each variable in the VALUES bracket. you could also remove half that code. by putting all the replacements into 1 if and just check if all are !empty, if so do str replce on all else `$check=false`

Comment: there are quotes.. and on my other sites it looks the same and just works...

Comment: have you echod out the `$sql` and pasted it directly into the database? Does that work?

Comment: add some error reporting:

`if (!mysqli_query($verbindung,$sql)){ 
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
}`

Comment: there is no error output given... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Veranstaltungen (Tag, Monat, Jahr, Stunde, Minute, Preis, Ort, AHelfer, BHelfer) VALUES ('".$Tag."', '".$Monat."', '".$Jahr."', '".$Stunde."', '".$Minute."', '".$Preis."', '".$Ort."', '".$AHelfer."', '".$BHelfer."')";
```

Well you forgot the concatenation "." (dot). Try this

Comment: you probably need`' " . variable . " '` to put quotes around the inserted data. But he said his format works elsewhere so not sure.

Comment: You are totally right, I forgot this. But yes as he said, there's no need but I will edit the answer to put it.

Comment: Did you try the last version I put ?

Comment: The dots are used to concatenate when you put variables in strings. I will try to see why it's not working give me few minutes

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know why it works now but it does...
After i tryed all ur tips and stuff i just ctrl + z to my first version posted above and it just worked...
Thanks a lot for all ur comments and answers!